# Custom gazebo world not loading in launchfile

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I have quite a confusing problem.
I created a custom Gazebo world that I am able to launch via:

> $ gazebo /home/georg/catkin_ws/src/ml/worlds/chapter1_3.world

as well as with:

> $ roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch world_name:="/home/georg/catkin_ws/src/ml/worlds/chapter1_3.world"

but with the following launchfile I can't manage

```
<launch>
    <arg name="world_file" default="$(find ml)/worlds/chapter1_3.world"/>

    <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
    <arg name="extra_gazebo_args" default="--verbose"/>

    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_file)"/>
        <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
        <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
        <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
        <arg name="extra_gazebo_args" value="$(arg extra_gazebo_args"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

And I can use `roscd ml`to navigate to /home/georg/catkin_ws/src/ml.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371111/custom-gazebo-world-not-loading-in-launchfile/) by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2021-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-05**:
What is the error that you are getting?

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2021-02-05**:
None, it just spawns the empty world.

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2021-02-05**:
After adding: `<arg name="verbose" value="true"/>` inside the include tag I can see the following error:

```
[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [$(arg]
[Err] [Server.cc:444] Could not open file[$(arg]
[Wrn] [Server.cc:359] Falling back on worlds/empty.world
```

Replaced `$(find ml)/worlds/chapter1_3.world` with the absolute path and still the same error.

However if I run `roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch verbose:="true" world_name:="/home/georg/catkin_ws/src/ml/worlds/chapter1_3.world` the world spawns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had a typo at `<arg name="extra_gazebo_args" value="$(arg extra_gazebo_args)"/>` ...

Edit: Forgot the closing bracket, also needed to remove the line `<arg name="extra_gazebo_args" value="$(arg extra_gazebo_args)"/>` completely for it to work

---

Originally posted by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) with karma: 183 on 2021-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-05**:
What was the typo?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-05**:
Also, can you please close this question as you have solved the issue at hand.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-06**:\

> Also, can you please close this question as you have solved the issue at hand.

no, please don't.

Questions with answers should have the answer marked as *accepted* by clicking the little checkmark icon to the left of the answer.

Closing questions is reserved for duplicates, off-topic questions etc. Answered questions should not be closed.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-06**:
@gvdhoom Oh okay.